# Open subgroups in local fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a local field. How to prove that $(K^*)^n$ is open in $K$ if and only if $\mathrm{char}(K)$ does not divide $n$?

Comment: So $K = Frac(\mathcal{O})$ where $\mathcal{O}$ has a unique maximal ideal $(\varpi)$ so that $K^* = \mathcal{O}^\times \varpi^\mathbb{Z}$ and $(K^*)^n = (\mathcal{O}^\times)^n \varpi^{n\mathbb{Z}}$. Could you define "open in $K$" in term of $\mathcal{O}, \varpi$ ?

Comment: @reuns, I don't understand something. The group $(K^*)^n = (\mathcal O^*)^n\omega^{n\mathbb Z}$. To be open it must contain a power of a maximal ideal but it does not contain it in any case as $\omega$ is only in powers dividing $n$.

Comment: $1+\varpi^n \mathcal{O}$ is open. If I define the metric $d(a,b) = |a-b| = 2^{-n}$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is such that $a-b \in \varpi^n \mathcal{O}, a-b \not \in \varpi^{n+1} \mathcal{O}$, does it help you ?

Comment: Can you be more specific on which implication ($\Leftarrow$ or $\Rightarrow$) you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ll give a relatively sketchy answer, depending on you to fill in the details. Accordingly, I’ll deal only with the case of characteristic $p>0$, since the mixed-characteristic case is not so interesting in this regard.

I think you will find it easy to show that $(K^*)^n$ is open in $K^*$ if and only if $(1+\mathfrak p)^n$ is open in $1+\mathfrak p$. (Here, $\mathfrak p$ is the maximal ideal of the ring of integers of $K$.) So I deal with this multiplicative subgroup of $K^*$ only.

If $n$ is prime to $p$, then $(1+\mathfrak p)^n$, the set of $n$-th powers of elements of $1+\mathfrak p$, is equal to $1+\mathfrak p$ itself: that is, every element of $1+\mathfrak p$ has an $n$-th root in $1+\mathfrak p$. You can see this with Hensel’s Lemma applied to $X^n-(1+\varepsilon)$, with $\varepsilon\in\mathfrak p$, or by noticing that the Binomial expansion for $(1+t)^{1/n}$ has no $p$ in the denominators of the coefficients.

If $p$ divides $n$, then you know that $(1+\mathfrak p)^p$ is just $1+\kappa[[\pi^p]]$, where $\kappa$ is the constant field of $K$. And there are elements of $K=\kappa((\pi))$ arbitrarily close to $1$ that are not in $1+\kappa[[\pi^p]]$, for instance $1+\pi^{Np+1}$ for $N$ as large as you like.

**EDIT**: My answer to your question about the equivalence between openness of $(K^*)^n$ in $K^*$ and openness of $(1+\mathfrak p)^n$ in $1+\mathfrak p$ :

First, $(K^*)^n\cap\mathscr O^*=(\mathscr O^*)^n$, for if something of valuation $0$ is an $n$-th power, it’s the $n$-th power of an element of valuation $0$. Therefore, if $(K^*)^n$ is open in $K^*$, its intersection with $\mathscr O^*$ will be open in $\mathscr O^*$, and so $(\mathscr O^*)^n$ will be open in $\mathscr O^*$.

Next, suppose that $(\mathscr O^*)^n$ is open in $\mathscr O^*$. As above, $(\mathscr O^*)^n\cap1+\mathfrak p$ is open in $1+\mathfrak p$. I now need only show that $(\mathscr O^*)^n\cap1+\mathfrak p=(1+\mathfrak p)^n$. Indeed, let $z\in\mathscr O$ with $z^n\in1+\mathfrak p$. If $q$ is the cardinality of $\mathscr O/\mathfrak p$, then $n|(q-1)$, and $z\equiv\zeta\pmod{\mathfrak p}$, where $\zeta$ is an $n$-th root of unity in $\mathscr O$. Then $z/\zeta\in1+\mathfrak p$ and $(z/\zeta)^n=z^n$, which is what I needed to show. ( That was not as easy as I expected when I wrote “I think you’ll find it easy”. )

Comment: I understand only partially the first statement. It's easy to prove that if $(1+\mathfrak p)^n$ is open then $ (K^*)^n $ is open but how to prove it in another direction?

Comment: And where do you use that the characteristic is $p>0$?

Comment: Characteristic is $p>0$ implies that $(1+\mathfrak p)^p=1+\kappa[[\pi^p]]$. Your other question requires more talk, and I’ll put it into an edit to my answer.